# How Read from Text File to JLabel or JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, text-files, jlabel, jtextarea

I'm trying to create a popup window that goes something like this:

Number of Games Played: 2
Total Score: 10
Average Score: 5

I have the numbers 2, 10, and 5 stored inside of a text file. I just want to be able to read the numbers from the text file into a (and this is where I get confused) a JLabel or a JTextArea? I also want to be able to clear the scores and reset them all to 0. Which I don't think should be too hard, but I could be wrong. Should I be storing the numbers into an ArrayList when I read them in?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HistoryPopUp {

    JFrame history;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel numGames, totalScore, avgScore;
    JTextArea games,score,aScore;
    JButton clearHistory;

    HistoryPopUp(){
        history = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        numGames = new JLabel("Number of Games Played: ");
        totalScore = new JLabel("Total Score: ");
        avgScore = new JLabel("Average Score: ");
        games = new JTextArea();
        score = new JTextArea();
        aScore = new JTextArea();


        clearHistory = new JButton();

        try {
            String textLine;
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("history.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            while((textLine=reader.readLine()) != null){
                textLine = reader.readLine();
                games.read(reader,"Something");
                score.read(reader, "seomthing");
                aScore.read(reader,"balh");
            }

            reader.close();

        }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("ABORT! YOU KILLED IT!!");
            }

        history.pack();
        history.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(games);
        panel.add(score);
        panel.add(aScore);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "History of Games Played", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
}
```

EDIT: Formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is you have 4 pieces of code all trying to read from the same pool of data, it's unlikely that `score` or `aScore` will have any data in the reader to read once `games` has finished

If you just want to use `JLabel`s you could do something like this...

```
String[] headers = {"Number of Games Played:", "Total Score:", "Average Score:"};
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[3];
for (int index = 0; index < labels.length; index++) {
    labels[index] = new JLabel();
    // Add label to screen
}

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("history.txt")))) {
    String text = null;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null && lineCount < 3) {
        System.out.println(text);
        labels[lineCount].setText(headers[lineCount] + " " + text);
        lineCount++;
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you want to use a `JTextArea`, you could do something like this...

```
String[] headers = {"Number of Games Played:", "Total Score:", "Average Score:"};
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 20);
// Add text area to container

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("history.txt")))) {
    String text = null;
    int lineCount = 0;
    while ((text = br.readLine()) != null && lineCount < 3) {
        System.out.println(text);
        textArea.append(headers[lineCount] + " " + text + "\n");
        lineCount++;
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

You could also use an array of `JTextField`s in a similar way

Comment: Thanks for the help! So adding labels to the screen, is that implemented the same as panel.add(insert label here)? Would I go through and name each of the new JLabels that were stored into the Array?

Comment: @Sailanarmo Yes, adding multiple labels is the same as adding any components and you've basically already done it. No, you would not "name" the labels, they are contained within an array, so you need to address through this array, `add(labels[index])` for example.  This is basic Java 101, if you're unfamiliar with this, I suggest you go back to basics before tackling something as complex as GUI programing

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out, it was a lot more simple than I thought. Thank you for your help! This has given me a new understanding on how this works!

Comment: @mKorbel I thought that to, but that data is not in the format that the OP wants to display it

Comment: @MadProgrammer JTable without JTableHeader, without lines around the cells

Comment: @mKorbel Sure, but `JTextArea#append` is simpler :P, but it comes down to requirements, I focused on fixing the reading issue ;)

Comment: plus one, sure, sure, sure, then but missing there `TAB` :-) instead of  `" "`

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Do not mix "persistence" (information is saved in a file) with "presentation".

Instead; read about Swing document models; or using the ["model view controller"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) approach.

But well, from the code you have written ... it seems that you are still having problems with very basic elements of Swing UI. The point is: there is javadoc; and excellent tutorials from Oracle. Don't expect other people to explain to you how to use them in detail. What I am saying is: first learn how to use the various UI elements; one by one; to understand how you get data into them; and how that information will then look like.

Then, when you understand the UI elements; think about a reasonable way to unpersist your data; and get it into your UI elements (and as said: doing all of that in the same piece of code is bad design; which should be avoided).